# can we resize column like excel with colresizable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

can we resize column with 'colresizable' like excel sheet ?

Example

All other column should automatically resize when i resize any one

Comment: Are you talking about http://quocity.com/colresizable/?

Answer (score 2):

now you can resize table columns independently using colResizable 1.6 and setting the attribute 'resizeMode' to 'overflow'. You can check and example on [its website](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples)

```
$("#overflowSample").colResizable({resizeMode:'overflow'});
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind the resizing of columns, please? It doesn't seem to be a trivial task.

Comment: in 'overflow' mode, drag on first time do not resize any column but after that it's working fine. what might be the problem, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, you only need to set the attribute "fixed" to false, and it work as you expect.

```
$("#nonFixedSample").colResizable({
    fixed:false,
    liveDrag:true
});
```

you can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pe88ouuu/1/) or check the "fixed" attr in the [colresizable website](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/)